# Should a shopping cart id be tied to a user id?

Tags: django

I want to create a shopping cart app that is tied to the user id. Mainly because if the user logs out, the items in the cart won't be deleted.

This is my first Django project so I'm not 100% sure if this is a good idea as the tutorials I'm following all use sessions for the carts, so it would be great if someone could give me some feedback.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from menulistapp.models import menulist

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):        
        try:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            new_obj = False
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            new_obj = True
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user)
            cart_obj.id = request.user.id

        return cart_obj

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(menulist, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Here's my views:

```
def cart_home(request):
    template = "cartapp/home.html"
    cart_id = request.user.id
    cart_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    context = {       
        "x": request.user,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should tie your cart object to user, because:

1. You will never lose the cart even if user logs out, or session expires.
2. Your business supports only one-cart-per-customer model.
3. You can follow up with user via email or other channels, if user has items in cart but hasn't checked out.
4. It's good idea for analytics purpose as well. You can user preferences buying patterns etc.

These are some basic reasons to tie your cart object to user. To support guest user / anonymous users you can tie cart with session as well.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why most of the teaching resources I've come across use sessions only?

Answer (score 1):

I think you implementation of `Model` looks okay, apart from custom manager. Django Manager has build it [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method, which is similar to yours. You can use it like this:

```
cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

and you should update your view like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def cart_home(request):
    template = "cartapp/home.html"

    cart_obj, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    context = {       
        "cart": cart_obj,  # you don't need to pass request.user because its already available in template via {{ user }}
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The code I wrote is basically an adaptation of the tutorial. He does touch on the fact that he is just doing what a get_or_create does, but never explained why. EDIT: Just wondering how would the get_or_create method assign user id?

Comment: you can check the source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L528

Comment: I just checked admin, and it turns out the cart_obj.id is not being set to request.user.id. Every time I refresh the cart, a new cart is being created. Help!

Comment: Maybe u can use '.get_or_create(user_id=request.user.id)'

Comment: I found out why it wasn't working. The object id(pk) can't be manually assigned when creating it. And Once an id number has been assigned, it can't be deleted or edited. So what I did was to create another field called "idn", so `cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user, idn=request.user.id)` and `cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(idn=request.user.id)`. So if I'm using get_or_create, it would be `cart_obj = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, idn=request.user.id)`